# Undefined variable Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am getting *Undefined variable* running this code using Laravel 8
**controller**

```
public  function index(){
   $customers =customers::all();
   return view('welcome',["customers"=>$customers]);
}
```

**Welcome.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($customers as $customers)
<tr>
 <td>{{ $customers->fullname }}</td>
 <td>{{ $customers->phone }}</td>
 <td>{{ $customers->item }}</td>
 <td>{{ $customers->itemprice }}</td>
 <td>{{ $customers->prepayment }}</td>
 <td>{{ $customers->created_at }}</td>
 <td>{{ $customers->updated_at }}</td>
</tr> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Welcome to SO , i think its better to show us the errors you have faced with the attempts you made and what you see the output as .
this is important for the community to engage more with your answer in the goal of solving your issue

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is in your blade: '@foreach ($customers as $customers)'
Could you try the following code:

### In your controller:

```
public function index()
{ 
    $customers = Customers::all();
    return view('welcome', ['customers' => $customers]);
}
```

### Welcome blade:

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $customer->fullname }}</td>
  <td>{{ $customer->phone }}</td>
  <td>{{ $customer->item }}</td>
  <td>{{ $customer->itemprice }}</td>
  <td>{{ $customer->prepayment }}</td>
  <td>{{ $customer->created_at }}</td>
  <td>{{ $customer->updated_at }}</td>
</tr> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: It wasn't solved by that.

Comment: @Zhilamo could you provide more details about the errors?

Comment: this is my error
ErrorException
Undefined variable $customers (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test-3\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
 any think i do  show me this error

Comment: @Zhilamo could you please edit your question and add your route file? Copy again your controller and your blade with the new version so the SO community can try help you

Comment: @Zhilamo Run `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`, because this _is_ the right answer. You were using the same variable name in the foreach loop which was breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

I've also got the same error a time.
This can be occur due to cache.

**Use clear cache command and try again later with same code**

use both command in  terminal

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan view:clear
```